# Passing multidimensional arrays to function_111

Tags: c++, function, multidimensional-array

```
do_something(int array[][])
{

}

int main()
{
    int array_length;
    cin>> array_length;
    int array[array_length][array_length];
    for()
    {
        "putting elements of array"
    }
}
```

I have seen people putting some `const int` so they can pass array to the function. Question is how do I pass a multidimensional array to the function if I don't know its size until it is entered.

Comment: For dynamic arrays, avoid using the standard arrays. Use `std::vector` and make your life simpler.

Comment: What is `function_111`?

Comment: C++ doesn't have variable-length arrays. Your declaration `int array[array_length][array_length];` is not valid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++, multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895340/c-multidimensional-array)

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm That doesn't explain how to pass arrays where the row size is variable.

Comment: @Barmar It doesn't explain how to pass two dimesional arrays, because you can't.  The duplicate I picked explains why you can't do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
int array[array_length][array_length];
```

This line will not compile. Unlike some other languages (Java, possibly), allocating an array of dynamic size is different than one of constant size. The `[]` notation will create a constant-size array, which will not work your attempt to pass it `array_length`. To allocate this array dynamically, use

```
int **array = new int*[array_length];
```

The you'll need to iterate through `array` and allocate each sub-array to the correct size with

```
array[i] = new int[array_length];
```

After this, you'll need to reference `array_length` when iterating through  `array`, as it is your only indication as to the size of the array.

Comment: Whoops, that's what I get for working quickly. And yes, vectors accomplish this nicely, but I thought it better for him to learn what the allocations really do before moving on to use the nice tools.